# Yii2 Redactor widget

Tags: php, image, yii2, thumbnails, redactor

I have a basic blog application which uses redactor as the means for inputting text. However when images are uploaded they are saved as HTML tags in the 'body' field. For example:

`<p>Test blog post</p><p><img src="/uploads/11/4d3ca0098c-dsc9011.jpg"></p>`

is what gets saved in the 'body' field.

This is how I am retrieving and displaying the data:

```
 foreach($dataProvider->getModels() as $post){
    echo Html::a('<div class="well well-sm" id="inner"><h3>'.$post->subject.'</h3>', '/post/view?id=' .$post->id);
    echo 'Posted By: ' .$post->user->username . ' <br/><i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> '.Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($post->updated_at)  . '<br/>Views: ' .$post->view_count .'</div>'; 
}
```

Is there a way I can add an 'if' statement in there to say

`if ($post->body contains < img > tag)`
`{ display < img > }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strstr()` searcjhes for a string within a string http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

So you could try:

```
if (strstr($post->body, '<img ')) {
```

Another way to grab the tag could be some regex, although it could mismatch depending on the HTML:

```
<?php

$html = '<html>
<head>
<etc />
</head>
<body>
<div><img src="blah.jpg" /></div><br />
</body>
</html>';

$regex = '#<img .*?\/>#';

preg_match($regex, $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Which will output `string(22) "<img src="blah.jpg" />"`

Here's the code https://3v4l.org/4NCNs

Here's the regex https://regex101.com/r/m1IYpx/1/

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed. Do you have any idea how I could then extract the image tag from the body?

Comment: This probably isn't the best way to do it then. You could load it in a DOMDocument then get elements by tag http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php. The other way is also trying a regex match (not recommended)